# Space Complexity of generating all possible binary search trees

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I used the following recursion algorithm to calculate the possible cases of binary search trees given its number of nodes being n

```
public List<TreeNode> generateTrees(int n) {
    if(n == 0){
        List<TreeNode> empty = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
        return empty;
    }
    return recurHelper(1, n);
}
public List<TreeNode> recurHelper(int start, int end){
    if(start > end){
        TreeNode nan = null;
        List<TreeNode> empty = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
        empty.add(nan);
        return empty;
    }
    List<TreeNode> result = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
    for(int i = start; i <= end; i++){
        List<TreeNode> left = recurHelper(start, i-1);
        List<TreeNode> right = recurHelper(i+1, end);
        for(TreeNode leftBranch:left){
            for(TreeNode rightBranch:right){
                TreeNode tree = new TreeNode(i);
                tree.left = leftBranch;
                tree.right = rightBranch;
                result.add(tree);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I wonder what is the space complexity for the recursion, should it be O(h), where h is the height of the tree?

I do not think so because at each level we are storing a result consisting of O(lG_l) elements, where l stands for the level and G_l stands for the number of possible trees with l nodes.

Then it seems to me that the space complexity of the recursion should be nG_n + ... + 1G_1.

Comment: Your theory seems correct. O(h) would be the time complexity of looking something up in the tree. The space complexity is indeed much higher.
What is your question exactly?

Comment: The solution I found online is claiming the space complexity should be nG_n and I do not know why.

Comment: In Big-O notation, it could be that O(nG_n) == O(nG_n + ... + 1G_1). It depends on G_n. If G_n is more than linear, the nG_n element will dominate, and you can ignore the other elements.